# Creating Custom Category Pages design in Magento

Tags: category-attribute

I need the "Main Categories" should have their own landing pages. For example, I am clicking on "Category 1" then it should take me to the landing page for categoriy 1 and should have its own design accordingly. Think of it as a "home page" for category 1.

Answer (score 2):

Each category can display `products` or a `static block`. `Or both`.

You can create `static blocks` for each category and assign them manually from the `admin UI`.

Also you can set different designs and layouts for each category from the `Design` tab in the `admin UI`.

Answer (score 1):

As marius said, in order  to customize a particular category, almost all things you can set up via admin itself.

For this go to

```
 Catalog  > Manage Categories  > [select category you need to customize]
```

Here you can see a `Design` tab, which is used to customize the category through layout updates.

Now if you need to do this via `layout XML File`, then there is another provision to do this.

For each category, magento generates a unique layout handle. So apply your custom design update to this layout handle. The general format of this unique layout handle is

```
  <CATEGORY_{ID}>.....</CATEGORY_{ID}
```

where `ID` is the category id of a category.